# Placing an ImageView on the X and Y cordinates

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-imageview

Why won't the ImageView place along the x and y Coordinates.  I am using a relative layout but for some reason the imageView is placing in the top left of the relative layout and it is not positioning to determined X and Y coordinate.

```
rel1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.canvas_container);
mImageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
image1();

public void image1(){
    //randomNumber();
    mImageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    mImageView1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spelling_);
    mImageView1.layout(130, 140, 240, 120);
    mImageView1.bringToFront();      
}
```

The xml code is going to be below

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/canvas_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/magnetboard" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

should I not declare ImageViews in the XML layout?

Also if you can provide resources it would be appreciated.  I searched a lot and couldn't decipher anything that would solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this(event inside XML) by position your image to be at top left of the parent. And then just give it marginTop(this will be your Y) and marginLeft(this will be your X).

Comment: @RichTalcik Margin give you more then just absolute position with x,y. You can be relative to bottom and to right as well.

Comment: now the imageview is hiding behind my background image for my relativelayout

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the padding/margin for the imageView instead, that's usually handled better in RelativeLayouts.

Answer (score 0):

call

```
    mImageView1.requestLayout();
```

after settings are done

```
 public void image1(){

  mImageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
  mImageView1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spelling_);
  mImageView1.layout(130, 140, 240, 120);
  mImageView1.bringToFront();
     mImageView1.requestLayout();
  }
```

Comment: in Your image1() method after doin Your settings